# How to relate band intensity to line intensity?

Tags: photon-emission

Let's define the intensity of an emission line $I(v',J'\rightarrow v'',J'')=N(v',J')A(v',J'\rightarrow v'',J'')$ as the number of photons emitted per unit time per unit volume due to the $(v',J')\rightarrow (v'',J'')$ line. Also, let's define the intensity of an emission band $I(v'\rightarrow v'')=N(v')A(v'\rightarrow v'')$ as the number of photons emitted per unit time per unit volume due to all transitions with $v'\rightarrow v''$. I would assume that one should have
$$ I(v'\rightarrow v'')=\sum_{J'}\sum_{J''}I(v',J'\rightarrow v'',J'')$$
I would like to know how I can carry out the summation in terms of e.g., the rotational partition function and the $A(v',J'\rightarrow v'',J'')$ transition probability expression [e.g., [Morton and Noreau, The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series, 95, 1, 301-343, 1994]](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/record/seri/ApJS./0095/1994ApJS...95..301M.html) to prove this equality if it indeed is valid.